# HTML+CSS Table row inline-block border no text

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem:
I have one table per row with different columns, and I need to have the first and the second column with the same width percentage so I have used inline-block inside td elements. My problem is that when I don't put text inside td the border of the cell renders differently than a td with text.

What can I do?

I have found that putting: `&nbsp;` inside, the td works fine, but I don't like this solution.

```css
table {
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana;
  background-color: yellow;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <table style="width:100%;">
      <tr>
        <td style="width:20%;display:inline-block;">a1</td>
        <td style="width:33%;display:inline-block;"></td>
        <td style="width:33%;display:inline-block;">a3</td>
        <td style="width:10%;display:inline-block;">a4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td style="width:20%;display:inline-block;">b1</td>
        <td style="width:33%;display:inline-block;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width:40%;display:inline-block;">b3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: `td {min-height:1.2em}` But I do wonder if a table is really the right construction for this, if your td's all need to be inline-blocks.

Comment: table is not a right way for this issue ! please use div with display flex

Comment: `display:inline-block` means that the `td` or the `element` takes the `width` and `height` of its contents if neither of them is provided explicitly.

So you must also provide a `height` to the td elements.

Comment: @Mohammad could you give me the same solution but using div with display flex please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

for td tag in css use min-height attribute

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

  <title>Ejemplo de estilos CSS en el propio documento</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    table {
      color: black;
      font-family: Verdana;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      min-height: 20px;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 1px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div style="width:100%">



    <table style="width:100%;">

      <tr>

        <td style="width:20%;display:inline-block;">a1</td>

        <td style="width:33%;display:inline-block;"></td>

        <td style="width:33%;display:inline-block;">a3</td>

        <td style="width:10%;display:inline-block;">a4</td>

      </tr>

    </table>


      <table style="width:100%">

        <tr>

          <td style="width:20%;display:inline-block;">b1</td>

          <td style="width:33%;display:inline-block;">&nbsp;</td>

          <td style="width:40%;display:inline-block;">b3</td>

        </tr>

      </table>

    </tr>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I don't like it so much because I have to change the min-height if I change the font-size.